# Removing first match until a new match

Tags: linux

I want to remove parts of a file starting from a match (including the first match) and until the second match (excluding the second match).

```
For example, I have the below:

Hello World
 test
Hello People

Final results :

Hello People
```

first match: "Hello World"
Remove until: "Hello"

I tried to use the below but didn't give the expected results :

```
sed -e  '/Hello World/,/Hello /!d' file
```

Comment: Try this: `sed -e '/Hello World/{:a;N;/^\([^ ]*\) .*\1/!ba;s/.*\n//;}' file`

Comment: Actually I want the code once it find Hellow World remove it and remove anything comes after it until it find a line start with Hellow 

I managed to make what I want within two lines :
sed -i "/^Hello World$/,/^Hello/{//p;d;}" "test"
sed -i "/^$Hello World$/d" "test"

I want to make it using single sed command

Comment: This is precisely what do my previous `sed` command!

Comment: could you explain briefly how this command works? and if I need to change "Hello" to something different what I should change? ( I mean the next match where It should stop deleting )
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is based on 1st word of line: `/^\([^ ]*\)` have to match word on further line: `\1`... If you change *Hello* for else... *Make your tries*.